# how to count the number of rows we have in a table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I simply want to count the total number of rows I have in a table.

I will put this number in parenthesis at the right of the categories names in my website's sidebar.

Comment: Check out the right hand column/sidebar of this page. It's a related questions list. You are likely to find the answer to your question there. Because it is very simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table
```

And from PHP

```
  $result = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM your_table');
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $count = $row['count'];
```

Alternatively if you were to use PDO (without a prepared statement)

```
  $count = (int) $pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table')->fetchColumn();
```

Then simply echo it

```
  echo '(Rows: ' . $count . ')';
```

Or if you want to be fancy using `printf`

```
  printf('(Rows: %d)', $count);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to do this from PHP in another way using mysql_num_rows() function.

Example:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM your_table');
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: This would work but it's slower and only recommended if you actually need those ID's. More information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485224/sql-php-which-is-faster-mysql-num-rows-or-select-count