# Which MySQL query is effective to get the total number of records

Tags: php, mysql

To get the total number of records, I usually use this query:

```
$total= mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM t_statistic WHERE pageid = $pid"));
```

but I got one the other query like below:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS num_rows FROM t_statistic WHERE pageid = $pid"));
$total = $data->num_rows;
```

Between the two queries above. Which is more quickly and effectively (when the total number of records in the millions)?

Comment: both assume the select query has succeeded, and will blow up if anything does wrong. assuming queries work is a bad way to go.

Comment: A possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485224/sql-php-which-is-faster-mysql-num-rows-or-select-count

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer the second query. It gives you already the record count, while the first query gives you the list of IDs (*not the count*), although it has been filtered but there are some cases when ID exist more than once in the table.

Answer (score 1):

The Second query is quick and efficient:

> SELECT COUNT(id) AS num_rows FROM t_statistic WHERE pageid = $pid

If you know about query optimisation. The query will only keeps only count in memory while calculating the answer. And directly gives number of rows.

Where as first query:

> SELECT id FROM t_statistic WHERE pageid = $pid

Keeps all the selected rows in memory. then number of rows are calculated in further operation.

So `second`  query is best in both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the second one.

Some engines, like MySQL can do a count just by looking at an index rather than the table's data.

I've used something like the following on databases with millions of records.

```
SELECT count(*) as `number` FROM `table1`;
```

Way faster than: mysql_num_rows($res);

BTW: The * in Count(*) basically means it won't look at the data, it will just count the records, as opposed to Count(colname).

Answer (score 0):

```
1) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_statistic WHERE pageid = $pid" --> count(*) counts all rows

2)SELECT COUNT(id) FROM t_statistic WHERE pageid = $pid" --> COUNT(column) counts non-NULLs only

3) SELECT COUNT(1) FROM t_statistic WHERE pageid = $pid" -->COUNT(1) is the same as COUNT(*) because 1 is a non-null expressions

Your use of COUNT(*) or COUNT(column) should be based on the desired output only.
```

So. Finally we have result is count(column) is more faster compare to count(*) .