# Using count(*) vs num_rows

Tags: php, mysql

To get number of rows in result set there are two ways:

1. Is to use query to get count

   `$query="Select count(*) as count from some_table where type='t1'";`

   and then retrieving the value of count.
2. Is getting count via num_rows(), in php.

so which one is better performance wise?

Comment: If your table has, say, a million rows, and you're using `num_rows()` in PHP to count them, then you need to pass a million rows from the database to PHP. If you're using `count(*)` on the database, then you're passing one row to PHP.

Comment: @andrewsi What are the performance differences? I mean, `COUNT(*)` will also have to count the rows, only on the DB server.

Comment: @andrewsi, why not leave an answer?

Comment: @Itay - assuming that both involve the same amount of work, it's better to use `count(*)` as that involves transferring less data. But your database software is designed to optimize your queries to run efficiently, so why not take advantage of that? As others have said, though, for a small amount of data, you're probably not going to see much actual difference.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary - had I but known it was going to get so many upvotes...

Comment: I answer to this question here:
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485224/sql-php-which-is-faster-mysql-num-rows-or-select-count/28861486#28861486

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your goal is to actually count the rows, use `COUNT(*)`.  `num_rows` is ordinarily (in my experience) only used to confirm that more than zero rows were returned and continue on in that case.  It will probably take MySQL longer to read out many selected rows compared to the aggregation on `COUNT` too even if the query itself takes the same amount of time.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few differences between the two:

1. `num_rows` is the number of result rows (records) received.
2. `count(*)` is the number of records in the database matching the query.

The database may be configured to limit the number of returned results (MySQL allows this for instance), in which case the two may differ in value if the limit is lower than the number of matching records. Note that limits may be configured by the DBA, so it may not be obvious from the SQL query code itself what limits apply.

Using `num_rows` to count records implies "transmitting" each record, so if you only want a total number (which would be a single record/row) you are far better off getting the `count` instead.

Additionally `count` can be used in more complex query scenario's to do things like sub-totals, which is not easily done with `num_rows`.

Answer (score 2):

count is much more efficient both performance wise and memory wise as you're not having to retrieve so much data from the database server. If you count by a single column such as a unique id then you can get it a little more efficient

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your implementation. If you're dealing with a lot of rows, count(*) is better because it doesn't have to pass all of those rows to PHP. If, on the other hand, you're dealing with a small amount of rows, the difference is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

`num_rows()` would be better if you have small quantity of rows and `count(*)` will give you performance if there are large number of rows and you have to select one and send it to php.