# PHP SQL get SELECT COUNT(user) to variable

Tags: php, mysql

How do I get the outcome of

```
SELECT COUNT(user) FROM game_paths WHERE user = '$user'
```

to a PHP variable

I tried

```
mysql_num_rows
```

but it returns nothing.

Comment: If you get nothing, your SQL returns nothing. Did you try it in phpMyAdmin and did it return anything there?

Comment: Example exist in php documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use mysql_result and get the first column of the result. Like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user) FROM game_paths WHERE user='$user'");
$count = mysql_result($result, 0);
```

You can also alias the column like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user) AS total FROM game_paths WHERE user='$user'");
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$count = $data['total'];
```

Which might be better if you're going to select several columns at the same time, and also for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. you need to use mysql_fetch_assoc or mysql_fetch_array functions

```
  $result = mysql_query(" SELECT COUNT(user) as total FROM game_paths WHERE user='$user' ");
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  
  echo $row['total'];
```

Or

```
  $result = mysql_query(" SELECT COUNT(user) FROM game_paths WHERE user='$user' ");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);  
  echo $row[0];
```

Docs Link: https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_fetch_array.asp

Note: mysql_* function are deprecated try to use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
  $result = mysql_query(" SELECT COUNT(user) FROM game_paths WHERE user='$user' ");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);  
  $count= $row[0];
```

or

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM game_paths WHERE user='$user'");
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

This will return the number of rows satisying the condition.

Comment: This query is way heavier on the server than to do COUNT() directly in MySQL. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485224/sql-php-which-is-faster-mysql-num-rows-or-select-count

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(user) AS user_count FROM game_paths WHERE user='$user'");
$result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$user_count=$result_array['user_count'];
```

Please use mysqli_ instead of mysql_ as its deprecated in the new version

Comment: mysql_queries don't include prepared statements. This means that it's possible to mix the query with the data, and that is a security flaw. You should use mysqli or PDO prepared statements. 

MySQLi is designed to work with MySQL 4.1.3 or higher and gives access to more advanced features in MySQL. It requires PHP 5.0 to use. It also gives you more control because you can change MySQL settings using MySQLi without stopping and starting the MYSQL server.

The MYSQL connecting library is designed for older versions of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Hey friend Try this code, ithink this will solve your problem

```
<?php
 $con=mysql_connect('hostname','DBusername','paassword');
  mysql_select_db('Db_name',$conn);
  $query="SELECT COUNT(user) as total FROM game_paths WHERE user='$user'"; 
   $result=mysql_query($query,$con);
   $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
   echo $row['total'];
  ?>
```