# Getting Value of COUNT

Tags: php, count

I have a php pagination script that I found online  ( http://papermashup.com/easy-php-pagination/), and it works fine and i want to modify it to better suit my needs and update it a little bit.  The problem i am having is that whilst it gives the number of results found, using

```
 echo $total_pages.' Results';
```

It will not return a zero if there are no results it just simply has no value.

Here is the code that counts the number of results.

```
 $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tableName";
 $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
 $total_pages = $total_pages[num];
```

I have tried to add an if statement so that if the results are 0 i can say sorry no matches found, but i can not get the value to display if there are no results.

I have tried to echo COUNT as a row along with num but no matter what i do, i can not seem to get it to display 0 results.

Comment: if there are no results I think there will be nothing to fetch. You should put the query in a conditional. Also that wont definitively mean there are `0` records because of query; could be error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending on your code:

```
 $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM {$tableName}";
 $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
 $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];
 if (!empty($total_pages)) {
     echo $total_pages . " Results found.";
 } else {
     echo "Sorry! No results found.";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the function mysql_num_rows();

```
$result_set = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result_set);
```

p.s. please try to use mysqli rather than simple mysql as its deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($num > 0)
{
    echo "Total records = ".$num;
}
else
{
    echo "Sorry no record found";
}
```

Comment: the `mysql_num_rows` is not as reliable as `COUNT(*)`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485224/sql-php-which-is-faster-mysql-num-rows-or-select-count and similar

Comment: may be you are right. but i always use `mysql_num_rows()` instead of `count(*)` and work v.well anyhow thanks for your suggestion